# Rewrite changing URL if last slash is omitted

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have rewrite rule that works okay, but ends up changing the visible URL if a trailing slash is omitted when going to an `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !main
RewriteRule /.* /~user/main$0
```

When someone visits

```
http://user.dev.example.com/utilities/pib/
```

The page works fine.  However, if they visit

```
http://user.dev.example.com/utilities/pib
```

They are redirected to

```
http://user.dev.example.com/~user/main/utilities/pib/
```

This still works fine, but I'd rather have the URL not change.  The server has other configuration that allows for `~user` in the URL to take you to `public_html` on the disc (where these files are located).  So the actual URL should be:

```
http://dev.example.com/~user/main/utilities/pib/
```

But it still leaves my name in the domain.  I'm not sure if I am even able to solve this problem, but I'm also not sure what other configuration could cause it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use mod_rewrite to append a trailing slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Add it above your first rule

Answer (score 0):

The above rules is not the cause of it. Check all the included configuration files in `conf.d` (or similar). If you set `AllowOverride All`, find all the `.htaccess` files with:

```
find /path/to/document/root -name .htaccess
```

and take a look at that.

I also suggest you turning on the `mod_rewrite` log:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

to see how the URI is parsed.